# Generating functional for free and interacting theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, interactions, correlation-functions, propagator

I'm asking probably a stupid question.

We define the generating functional for free theories as
$$
Z_0[J] = \int D \psi e^{i\int d^4x \left[ L_0(x) + J_l(x)\psi^l(x) \right]}
$$
with $L_0$ the free lagrangian density, while for interacting theories we define it as
$$
Z[J] = \int D \psi e^{i\int d^4x \left[ L(x) + J_l(x)\psi^l(x) \right]}.
$$
with $L$ the total lagrangian density.

What's the difference between this two definition? In which case do I have to use the first or the second? Can you give me any examples to better understand?
I think my difficulties are understanding the difference between interacting and free theories.

Comment: the difference is $L\neq L_0$. You use the first one if your particles are free, and the second one if they are not. For example, $L_0=(\partial\phi)^2$ and $L=L_0+\phi^4$.

Comment: but what's the sense of computing a propagator for free particles?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Why not flesh that out some into an answer?